# using apache camel REST DSL using restlet adding swagger

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, swagger, restlet, swagger-ui

I am using apache camel REST DSL using springboot. All the configuration works fine. Now I want to add REST documentation using camel swagger java component. The REST DSL and swagger java, works out of the box. I can see the JSON output of the exposed REST services.

Now Question, what steps I need to follow, such that i can view camel REST documentation using swagger-ui?

I searched for answers, however the only solution was to download swagger-ui from github and "copy" `<dist>` folder to project, this doesn't seems to work, getting 404. URL i am using is `localhost:8081\rest\index.html`.

I liked the spring-fox swagger2, is it something can be supported in camel?

Answer (score 1):

See this example which includes swagger ui.
https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-swagger-xml

The index.html file has more details how to access the swagger ui when the application runs.